# OSX User level application Preferences (plist) are not loaded after binary modification

Tags: osx, patching, binary-editing, macos

I am working on a project that requires to modify an existing OSX application's `dylib` binary (few bytes to correct an obsolete URL). I do not have access to the application source code nor the code signing certificates. After patching the application everything works perfectly except it does not load its application `plist` file from `~/Library/Preferences`.

Even without patching/modifying the application if I do:

```
codesign -s "Local Codesign" -f ./lib<name>.dylib
```

and execute the application it does not read its properties from

```
~/Library/Preferences/<application id>.plist
```

including previously opened files or connected servers. If I copy back the original (developer signed) `dylib` then everything works fine: properties are read back again.

One strange thing: even with my local signed binary which is unable to read the `plist` file if I change something the changes are written back. So if this is an OSX security related stuff seems it's only affects reads.

Now my questions and assumptions:

- Am I right when I am assuming that this is some kind of OSX security mechanism that ensures application `plist` data cannot be accessed from a non-same-developer signed binary? If yes, why can it write and protects reads only?
- Does any of you find similar issue when modified an OSX binary?
- How can I debug this behaviour?
- And yes: any solutions?

Any comments and feedbacks are welcome.

Comment: how did you determine that the application does not load the plist from that location and that it did before?

Comment: If I change the signature of any of the libraries then the UI does not show "Recent files" and "Recent connections". If I change back the libraries to the original signed ones everything works well. Also, in case I change the libraries I see security exceptions in OSX Console: `code requirement check failed (-67063), client is not Apple-signed`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find some hints by googling the error message, e.g.:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40705362/422797

Looks like it's not related to the plist but possibly to some security APIs (e.g. keychain access or `SecCodeCheckValidity`) used by the program.
Apparently the OS caches signing info based on the file's vnode, and if you replace it in-place that invalidates the signature. The linked answer suggests some workarounds.

Comment: This was one of the issue. After I changed the process flow to 1) move the file 2) sign it in /Application folder with a proper apple signed signature it was able to read the plist. Thanks!